# What is the probability? (distribution of sample proportions)

Tags: probability

A jury is to be selected for a proceeding in which the accused is alleged to have stolen money from a business partner. According to existing data, 40% of potential jurors have been a victim of a major theft at some point in their life that will make them unfairly prejudicial against the accused.

If 48 jurors are randomly chosen, calculate the probability that at least half of them will be unfairly prejudicial in this way assuming that the distribution of sample proportions is normal.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Mean, variance, standard deviation, continuity correction?

Comment: I was looking at that for an hour.  it is distribution of sample proportions. what i got is z=(0.5-0.4)/(0.4*(1-0.4)/48)^1/2 which is 1.414213562. there i end up :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calculated $z=\dfrac{0.5-0.4}{\left(\frac{0.4(1-0.4)}{48}\right)^{1/2}} =1.414213562$

You would have got the same value with $\dfrac{24-48\times 0.4}{\left(48 \times 0.4\times (1-0.4)\right)^{1/2}} $

If you look this up in your normal cumulative distribution function table, it might give you something like $\Pr(Z \le z) = \Phi(z) = 0.9213505$ and so $\Pr(Z \gt z)= 0.07864954$ and this might be what you are looking for as an answer.

Since you are using a normal approximation to a discrete random variable,  you might do better with a continuity correction, which could involve starting by calculating $\dfrac{23.5-48\times 0.4}{\left(48 \times 0.4\times (1-0.4)\right)^{1/2}}$ and thus instead coming up with a probability of about $0.1025956$ instead.

As an aside, the actual probability is about $0.1033814$ found using the R code

```
1 - pbinom(23, 48, 0.4)
```

so the continuity correction is quite helpful in getting you close.

Comment: In the second line you have calculated $P(X\leq 24)$ ? And  when you used the continuity correction you have calculated $P(X\leq 23)$ ?

Comment: Using a normal approximation without the continuity correction, the attempt is to calculate $\Pr(X \ge 24)$, which unfortunately for a continuous distribution is the same as $\Pr(X \gt 24)$.  There is a similar issue attempting to calculate  $\Pr(X \gt 23)$, which for a continuous distribution is the same as $\Pr(X \ge 23)$ rather than $\Pr(X \ge 24)$.   The continuity correction is therefore to calculate  $\Pr(X \gt 23.5)$ as being somewhere between $\Pr(X \gt 23)$ and $\Pr(X \ge 24)$

Comment: That interesting, where did you get those values (Pr(Z≤z)=Φ−1(z)=0.9213505
Z
z
Φ
1
z
0.9213505
  and so Pr(Z>z)=0.078649540. i see on the table and i can't see them.  for line 1.414 i have for 0.00-0.9192 0.01-0.9207 0.02-0.9222 0.03-0.9236 0.04-0.9251 0.05-0.9265 0.06-0.9279 0.07-0.9292 0.08-0.9306 0.09-0.9319  co according my table it should be 0.9207?

Comment: I should have written $\Phi(1.414213562) = 0.9213505$, which I took from R's `pnorm(sqrt(2))`  Your tables should show at least $\Phi(1.41) = 0.9207$ and $\Phi(1.42) = 0.9222$ as shown for example at http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~athienit/Tables/Ztable.pdf

Comment: great, thanks :)